# How can refresh a ResultSet in Java

Tags: mysql, connection

I want to use a MySQL with JDBC in a loop, because I have to poll a table frequently for new data which comes in from other clients. But even if I close the ResultSet, the connection and the statement, is the old result at the next round still there. I cannot get a new result, unless I restart the program. What is my mistake?

I condensed the code for the necessary.

```js
    import java.sql.*;

public class Eventmgr {private static String in_text;
    private static String in_typ;
    
    private static Connection connection;
    
    private static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.x.x:3306/xxxx"; 
    private static String username = "xxx"; 
    private static String password = "xxx"; 
        
    public static void start() throws SQLException {
                
        while(loop_count > 0) {
                if (loop == false) {
                loop_count = loop_count -1;}
        
        
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, nummer, text, typ from inbox order by id asc limit 1") ;
            while(rs.next()) {
                in_id = rs.getString("id");
                in_nummer = rs.getString("nummer");
                in_text = rs.getString("text");
                in_typ = rs.getString("typ");}
            connection.close();
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
            System.out.println("still running");

            }
        }
}
```

Anybody has an idea what my problem is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid, and it was my mistake...

The problem is. I check on the variable "in_id" and if there is no new result "while(rs.next())" dont deliver a new value, so I need to reset that variable with "in_id = null;" at the end of the loop.

Now it works...